# How can I give previous variable to current variable?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list as below in python. In this list, the numbers are equal in some cases, but in cases where the numbers are equal, I want to print the value in the previous inequality in the 'c' column.

```
conditions  = [ df[a] > df[b], (df[a] == df[b]), df[a] < df[b] ]

choices     = [ "A bigger than B", 'same', 'B bigger than A' ]

df["c"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | B bigger than A |
| 2 | 2 | same |
| 2 | 2 | same |
| 3 | 2 | A bigger than B |
| 3 | 3 | same |
| 3 | 3 | same |
| 3 | 6 | B bigger than A |

i want to do

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | B bigger than A |
| 2 | 2 | B bigger than A |
| 2 | 2 | B bigger than A |
| 3 | 2 | A bigger than B |
| 3 | 3 | A bigger than B |
| 3 | 3 | A bigger than B |
| 3 | 6 | B bigger than A |

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the first values are equal?

Comment: im thinking you could keep this code and at the end add something like                     df['c'][ df['c'] == 'same' ]=df['c'].shift(-1)

Comment: @ChristianTrujillo I think that will cause an issue for cases where there are two "same" in a row

Comment: First value is not so important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values are equal, use `previous` as the comment. Otherwise, set `comment` conditionally.

```
previous = "same"
for i in range(len(df)):
  if df.loc[i,"A"] == df.loc[i,"B"]:
    comment = previous
  else:
    comment = "A bigger than B" if df.loc[i,"A"] > df.loc[i,"B"] else "B bigger than A"
  df.loc[i,"C"] = comment
  previous = comment
```

Result

```
  A  B                C
0  3  1  A bigger than B
1  1  2  B bigger than A
2  3  1  A bigger than B
3  1  1  A bigger than B
4  1  3  B bigger than A
```

Comment: Thank you. There does not appear to be a problem for now.